# Опера не подключает js

Tags: xml, xslt, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему на [этом](http://prozaik.16mb.com/xml/filmsflame_onclient/) сайте в `opera12.01` не подключаются яваскрипты?

Answer (score 1):

Немножко правды из консоли:

Uncaught exception: Error: WRONG_ARGUMENTS_ERR

```
Error thrown at line 7, column 3127 in <anonymous function: getStyle>(C) in http://prozaik.16mb.com/xml/filmsflame_onclient/js/cufon/cufon.shoqolate.comjscufon-yui.js:
    return new a(B.getComputedStyle(C,null))
called from line 7, column 8686 in <anonymous function>() in http://prozaik.16mb.com/xml/filmsflame_onclient/js/cufon/cufon.shoqolate.comjscufon-yui.js:
    E=n.getStyle(document.body).isUsable()
called from line 7, column 367 in <anonymous function: ready>() in http://prozaik.16mb.com/xml/filmsflame_onclient/js/cufon/cufon.shoqolate.comjscufon-yui.js:
    F()
```

Comment: насколько я помню cufon это что-то со шрифтами связано, лучше использовать шрифты гугла для этого, а этот удалить, а возможно cufon это резиновый шрифт, но хоть убей не помню.

Comment: я пробовал полностью вырезать скрипты, связанные с куфоном. результат тот же

кроме того я использую нелицензионный шрифт в этом проекте. в шрифтах от гугл его явно нет(

Comment: есть ещё один сайт, сделанный по этому же шаблону. в нем cufon не используется. js тоже не работает рпи этом. ссылку нет смысла постить, на слово поверьте.

хотя спсибо, что указали на ошибку в консоли. хоть она и не критичная